# How do you create pillar content pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I'm trying to create a guide/pillar page with subpages and I'm kinda lost. I'm going for something like this: https://www.digitalmarketer.com/digital-marketing where you have /main-keyword/sub-keyword slugs.

Are there any tutorials on how to do that? I can't find any.

Thanks

Comment: Just set the parent for a page and it will appear as a sub page in the URL.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that option. And I was also confused by the fact that posts are nested under a category name.